# Correct hashmap typing as function argument in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, styled-components, keyof

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const IconWrapper = styled.Text`
  font-family: MyFont;
`;

const glyphs = {
  'logo': '\ue94e',
  'minus': '\ue900',
  'plus': '\ue901',
...
};

interface IconProps {
  glyph: string;
}

const Icon: React.FC<IconProps> = ({ glyph }) => {
  return (
    <IconWrapper>{glyphs[glyph]}</IconWrapper>
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

I need instead of `glyph: string` pass explicit type `enum` (or keyof glyphs).
That could be probably enum but I don't want to duplicate the whole structure once again.

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keyof` keyword combined with `typeof` to narrow down the type

```
const Icon = ({ glyph: keyof typeof glyphs }) => {
```

For readability, you can define another type like below :

```
type GlyphIcon  = keyof typeof glyphs;
const Icon = ({ glyph: GlyphIcon  }) => {
```

Comment: Oh yeah... I see. It was simple. Thanks! Another question: is that could be considered as a best practice?

Comment: @featureoffuture you may have some small improvement like the updated answer.